# Error while Running a simple Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to run a simple Shiny App that takes a couple of text inputs to generate an SQL statement.  I keep getting the following error when I have the textInput control uncommented.

Error in match.arg(position) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

The code I am running is:
**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

 # Application title
 titlePanel("SQL Developer"),

 # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  sliderInput("topnrows",
              "Number of rows to show:",
              min = 1,
              max = 100,
              value = 50)
),

textInput("text1", label = "Text input", value = "Enter text..."),
# textInput("dbName",
#           label="Enter the Database Name",
#           value="Enter Database Name"),
# textInput("tableName",
#           "Enter the Table Name"),


# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
 h3( textOutput("sqlText"))
)
)
))
```

**server.R**
    library(shiny)

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {


 output$sqlText <- renderPrint({


 paste("select top ", input$topnrows, " * from trial.table",sep='')
 })

 })
```

Commenting the textInput() lines, I can run the app.  I haven't been able to figure out what I was missing in the textInput function for the error to show up.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to put all input within your `sidebarPanel()` :

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

        # Application title
        titlePanel("SQL Developer"),

        # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
        sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                        sliderInput("topnrows",
                                    "Number of rows to show:",
                                    min = 1,
                                    max = 100,
                                    value = 50),
                 textInput("dbName",
                           label="Enter the Database Name",
                           value="Enter Database Name"),
                 textInput("tableName",
                           label="Enter the Database Name",
                           value="Enter the Table Name"),
                textInput("text1", label = "Text input", value = "Enter text...")
        )                
                ,


                # Show a plot of the generated distribution
                mainPanel(
                        h3( textOutput("sqlText"))
                ))

))
```